# Options vs Query Parameters in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

Apache camel components page have fields under option and query parameters but no clear path position for parameters , from samples I was able to make out they go along options .
I would like to know the difference between options and query parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options are used to configure Component and Query Parameters are used while creating endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

When an application with Apache Camel starts, it registers the routes in the Camel Context, and once the context is started, components present in from () and to () cannot be modified, for example:

```
String param = "a = xxxx & y = bbb";
...
to ("http4: //api.xxx.yy?" + stop)
...
```

It will only be evaluated at startup, so even if the value of the string in the param variable changes, the route will always use `a=xxxx&y=bbb` as the default since it has already been initialized in the context of Camel (you can see Camel recording the routes in the logs during application startup).

The options can undergo changes not only in construction, depending on the design of the component in question, but can also be exposed for configuration via starters using `application.yml` or `application.properties` or via java as in the example below:

**application.properties**

```
camel.component.http.http-configuration=br.com.pack.impl.MyHttpConfiguration
```

**In java**

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.setProxyAuthMethod("Digest");
config.setProxyAuthUsername("myUser");
config.setProxyAuthPassword("myPassword");

HttpComponent http = context.getComponent("http", HttpComponent.class);
http.setHttpConfiguration(config);

from("direct:start")
  .to("http4://www.google.com/search");
```

I hope it helped to clarify a little more